# Using <dependencies> tag within <reporting> in Maven pom.xml

Tags: xml, maven, checkstyle

I am trying to use the latest version of Checkstyle in my `<reporting>` section of my pom.xml, but keep getting the error

```
Malformed POM pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'dependencies' (position: START_TAG seen ...</configuration>\n        <dependencies>... @86:23)  @ pom.xml, line 86, column 23
```

The following is the relevant section of my pom.xml. Line 86 is the line `<dependencies>`.

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <configuration>
        <configLocation>config/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
          <version>7.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

This code was copied directly from the [Maven Checkstyle plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html) website. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<dependencies>` out side of  `<reporting>` tag.

See the following example :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>config/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Other plugins -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reporting plugins** such as Checkstyle are special kinds of plugins that can be configured both in **reporting** or **build** section. depending on where we do the configuration, some limitations might apply.

When we configure the reporting plugin in the reporting section, we can not use **execution** and **dependency** tags however these tags are allowed when we define the plugin in the build section.

The problem in this question is that the dependency is defined in the wrong place (within the reporting section).